# Is there a way to auto-generate a Mule mflow file based upon the xml?

Tags: mule, mule-flow

I want to know if there's a way to do this, to auto-generate from zero an mflow file based upon the xml files.

If not, how do you guys manage to merge with SVN those mflow files? its basically impossible! you need to manually merge them from the IDE Mule UI using drag-and-drop or going into the xml and adding that manually as well.

Thanks.

Comment: This is an important question that still needs a good answer. Conflict resolution on the .mflow files is just guess work.

Answer (score 2):

As noted elsewhere in stackoverflow, the flows directory and any .mflow files should not be committed to version control systems like git.[1]

The mflow files are generated by studio based on the XML file for your app that is stored in src/main/app/

So, after cloning a git project, for example, that does not have mflow files, running mvn studio:studio (to generate the Studio meta data), and then double clicking on that xml file, the .mflow file will be regerated (and the flows directory created, if nec.)

I just verified this with Anypoint Studio May 2014 Release (new name)

[1] http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Preparing+a+gitignore+File

Answer (score 0):

Using mule studio those files are mirrored real-time on saves (file deletes or edits). So if you want to do this outside of MS then you will need an automation tool to do it like ant. In general its better to work with the files in the /flow folder.

Comment: I understand, but if you want to merge changes from repository to your local changes in those mflow files its basically impossible to merge them ... its like the xml is randomly created every time you open it, i mean... the order of the components and data isn't in the same place every time... so basically you will end up having like 23049230 differences and that's not real

Comment: we've never had issues with flow files and svn. whats your team methodology for editing them? you need to agree on one way for the whole team.

Comment: Mulesoft now recommends putting the flows in the .gitignore.

http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Preparing+a+gitignore+File

However, like the OP, I can't figure out how to generate the flows from the xml after initially cloning the repo.

Comment: @rhuffstedtler Can't you write a script to do it after checkout and later if your not using studio you could watch the xml files then generate the flows on updates, I like **node.js** so I would set up a node.js watch+copy task

Comment: This answer hints that there may be a way to do this with ant or some other tool. Point out how that is done and *then* we may have an answer :)

Comment: The only approach I'm aware of is the one @Rondo explains: never ever commit these files, let Studio regenerate them. I've heard rumours of abandoning them: I hope it really happens because these `.mflow` files are almost completely useless and totally confusing.

Comment: @DavidDossot yeah that makes sense to me, they are very confusing! Better to only have 1 location for the same logical content (flow xml).

Comment: @DavidDossot, yes, .mflows are in the process of being removed from Studio. This will happen in one of the upcoming milestone releases of Studio this summer.